# Discriminator Based Multi-Tenancy Filtering Using Hibernate Search

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am attempting to add full text search to an entity using hibernate-search. Our schema uses discriminator based multi-tenancy, where each tenant is a `park` with an id. The model looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class ProductModel {
  @Field
  // park is the tenant 
  private Long parkId;

  @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
  @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
  private String name;

  @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
  @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
  private String description;
}
```

When performing full text search, I will always be filtering based on a `parkId`. Would it make sense to annotate the `parkId` with `@Field`, and then add that filter to the lucene query like so:

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb
  .bool()
    .must(qb.keyword().onFields("parkId").matching(parkIdFilter)) 

    // any aditional queries, like on name, description
   .must(qb.keyword().onFields(fields).matching(textQuery).createQuery())
  .createQuery();
```

Or is there a better way to handle multi-tenancy using hibernate search with discriminator columns? I've seen the [example mentioned in the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-multi-tenancy) but don't know how to apply that to my particular use case.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest path would be to use [Hibernate ORM's built-in multi-tenancy support](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy-hibernate), which is currently limited to either schema-based or database-based multi-tenancy. If you do, Hibernate Search will handle multi-tenancy automatically, no need for you to do anything special.

I must admit Hibernate ORM's doc is a bit puzzling, since the discriminator strategy is mentioned, but not implemented.
I *think* (not sure) that you can set the `hibernate.multiTenancy` property to `DISCRIMINATOR`, and the only effect will be that Hibernate ORM will require you to use tenant IDs every time you open a session.

If that is the case (you will have to check), then you could do just that: set the `hibernate.multiTenancy` property to `DISCRIMINATOR`, and make sure to pass the tenant IDs every time you create a session. Then Hibernate Search will handle multi-tenancy out of the box, no additional work needed. You will still have to implement the multi-tenancy yourself on the database side, but at least on the index side you won't have to do anything.

If you don't want to use the built-in feature, then yes, you will have to annotate the `parkId` with `@Field`. I would recommend avoiding manually creating a boolean query just for that, though; you can simply use [full text filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-filter-fulltext).